# Can evidence be used as verb?

Tags: verbs

Is it fine to used evidence as verb?

For eg. the study evidenced that....

If not, what other better word can be used in the place of evidence as a verb?

Note: I find evidence can be used as a verb in Lexico dictionary and Merriam Webster but still I would like to know the common usage of it.

Comment: There is evidence that it is in use as a verb, but I don't encounter it very often. In your example sentence I think "the study *showed* that..." or "the study *found evidence* that..." would be better.

Comment: Dictionaries _study_ common usage, and base their entries upon it.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=evidenced&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cevidenced%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cevidenced%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly find similar examples if you look hard enough:

> The study also evidenced significant associations among 3 health risk indices

(From Associations Between Perceptions of School Connectedness and Adolescent Health Risk Behaviors in South African High School Learners)

[COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (my search: `* EVIDENCE_v*`) shows that by far the most common use of the verb is in the phrase “as evidenced by”, followed by regular passive constructions such as “is evidenced”.

A more common word here would be “the study **found**...”

Comment: Thanks to all for the well-thought replies.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes, the word **evidence** can be used as a verb. You can find more details in the Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary.

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/evidence_2

In US English more than in UK English, using nouns as verbs has become a relatively common practice.

Comment: Although it is true that there are, in the actual contemporary usage, quite a few examples of nouns (including *evidence*) turned into verbs, it should be noted that opinions differ on whether, as a matter of good style, such 'verbing' should be welcomed or discouraged.

Comment: @ jsw29 Thanks for the reply